# TypeScript error in http-proxy-middleware when build reactjs application using bitbucket pipeline

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bitbucket-pipelines

I have one issue with react build process using bitbucket pipeline , its working before few days ago and not its showing below error without changing in code

please help me to fix this issue also let me know if there are any issue from react side for any package version

[image]